# If $x^p - x - a$ has no root in $F$ then $x^p - x - a$ is irreducible in $F$ with $F$ is a field with char $p$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

I need to prove that if $f(x) = x^p - x - a$ has no root in $F$ then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$, where $F$ is a field with characteristic $p$.

My attempt so far:

Let $L$ be a spliting field of $f(x)$ over $F$ and $u$ be a root of $f(x)$ in $L$. In other words, $u^p - u - a = 0$.

Assume that $f(x)$ is reducible in $F[x]$, which means $f(x) = g(x).h(x)$, where $\deg g \ge 1$, $\deg h \ge 1$.

This implies $x^p - x - (u^p - u) = g(x).h(x)$ (I substite $a$ by $u^p - u$)

Or $(x - u)^p - (x - u) = g(x).h(x)$ (in $L$ we have $(a+b)^p = a^p + b^p$)

I'm not sure how to continue from this point. My goal is to somehow prove that $u$ must belong to $F$, which concludes the proof.

Please give me a hint. Thank you.

Comment: Hint 1: if $u$ is a root of $f$, what do the other roots of $f$ look like? Hint 2: Consider an automorphism taking $u$ to some other root, what happens if you keep applying the automorphism?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, are all the other roots of $f$ has the form of $u + ke$, where $k \in \overline{1,(p-1)}$ and $e$ is the unit of $F$? 
About the automorphism, do you mean that the automorphism which preserves all element in $F$ and taking $u$ to $u + ke$ for some $k$, sir?

Comment: Oh wait. Then $f(x) = (x - u)(x - u - e)...(x - u - (p-1)e)$, thus $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ all must receive those linear factors as their own factors.
Assume $g(x) = (x - a_1)(x - a_2)...(x - a_j)$ where $a_i$ all have the form $u + ke$. Since $g(x) \in F[x]$, we have $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_j \in F$, or $ju + Be \in F$ with some $B$. This implies $ju \in F$ where $0 < j < p$, which implies $u \in F$.

if I take this way, can I finish my proof, sir? Please verify.